# donde puedo encontrar el icono de debian para modificarlo

Tags: linux, debian, icono, splash

hola buenas donde puedo encontrar el logo de debian para modificarlo por una imagen png [![quierocambiar la imagen que dice debian ]
por otra imagen pero no encuentro donde esta ubicada agradeceria su ayuda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Me parece que te refieres a las imágenes de plymouth o bootsplash.
De ser así, sugiero que busques dentro de las siguientes rutas: */usr/share/plymouth/themes/*
*/usr/share/images/desktop-base/*